# Clone an entity with a ManyToMany Association

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two entities that have a ManyToMany bidirectional association: `$foo` and `$bar`. $foo is the owning side. They are joined by a middle table: `foo_bar`.

I need to **clone** the `$foo` entity so that the new entity keeps all the associations with `$bar`. It should **not** create new `$bar` records, just duplicate the records in joining table `foo_bar`. So I'll have two `$foo` objects, both pointing to the same collection of `$bar` entities.

How should this be handled?

### $foo object:

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sitetheory\CoreBundle\Entity\Bar", inversedBy="foos", cascade={"detach"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="foo_bar")
 */
protected $bars;
```

### $bar object:

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sitetheory\CoreBundle\Entity\Foo", mappedBy="bars")

 */
protected $foos;
```

### Failed Attempts

I've tried making `$foo cascade={"**persist**", "detach"}` but that doesn't work: it tries to create NEW `$bar` objects which is not what we want.

I've tried to re-associate the relationships (thinking the new object hashes would trigger a new persist) but that doesn't work either. On the `$foo` `__clone()` function:

```
public function __clone() {
    $bars = $this->getBars();
    if (!empty($bars)) {
        $this->setBars(new ArrayCollection());
        foreach ($bars AS $bar) {
            $this->addBar($bar);
        }
    }
}
```

That just gives the error:

> A new entity was found through the relationship
> 'Sitetheory\CoreBundle\Entity\Foo#bars' that was not configured to
> cascade persist operations for entity: Woo. To solve this issue:
> Either explicitly call EntityManager#persist() on this unknown entity
> or configure cascade persist this association in the mapping for
> example @ManyToOne(..,cascade={"persist"}).

But if I do add persist on the entity, it gives a different error about inserting a new Bar, which of course I don't want it to do anyway.

## UPDATE

Evidently, the problem was that there should not have been a `cascade={"detach"}`. When I removed that, the cloning worked automatically.

Answer (score 2):

You can easly copy objects and their properties using https://github.com/myclabs/DeepCopy

it's simple like this

```
$deepCopy = new DeepCopy();
$myCopy = $deepCopy->copy($myObject);
```

And also there's a very good documentation.

Comment: Thanks. Do you know the native process for cloning ManyToMany associations?

Answer (score 0):

1. It depends on owning side. In your case $foo object is owner of relation. If you clone it - cloned child will have childs. If you will clone $bar object - you will need to alter __clone function with something like

```php
public function __clone() {
   $foos = $this->getFoos();

   foreach ($foos AS $foo) {
      $foo->addBar($bar);
   }
}
```

2. make sure you have cascade persist at the owning side

```
/*
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Sitetheory\CoreBundle\Entity\Bar", inversedBy="foos", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="foo_bar")
 */
protected $bars;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#[ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity:Bar::class, inversedBy='foos', cascade= cascade: ['detach'])
#[ORM\JoinTable(name:"foo_bar")
        
protected $bars;
        
public function __clone()
    {
        $bars = new ArrayCollection();
        foreach ($this->bars as $bar) {
            $bar->addFoo($this);
            $bars->add($bar);
        }
        $this->bars = $bars;
    }
```